# Using Office Script in Excel, how do I create a Word Doc and write some text to it?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, cpu-word, office-scripts

I just want to create a new Word document from within Excel and make it available as an Office Script.
It sounds simple enough but I just cannot get it right.
I am beginning to think it's not possible.

Ultimately I am getting Open_AI to analyze an Excel sheet and then create a report with the text returned, but just getting to create a "Hello world" Word Document is proving difficult.

What am I missing?

This is the script I am working with:

```js
// Import the WordScript module
import * as WordScript from "OfficeScript/word";


// Create a new Word document and add text
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 
    // Create a new Word application object
    let wordApp = new WordScript.WordApplication();

    // Create a new Word document
    let doc = await wordApp.createDocument();

    // Add some text to the document
    let paragraph = doc.addParagraph("Hello, World!");

    // Apply bold formatting to the text
    paragraph.font.bold = true;

    // Save the document to the Documents folder
    let documentsFolder = wordApp.getDocumentsFolder();
    let filePath = documentsFolder + "\\MyDocument.docx";
    await doc.save(filePath);
}
```

I have tried a number of ways to create a Word document from within Excel using Office Script, but I just cannot access the Office object.  What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that this would actually work? Office scripts is light, it’s not capable of full office integration.

Comment: ChatGPT suggested it would work.

Comment: Maybe ask it to clarify if that’s for Office Scripts. It’s not possible as far as I am aware. It may be for OfficeJS.

Comment: This isn't possible, as described. There's no such thing as `WordScript`. You'll need to make [a Power Automate flow to use an Office Script to read data from the workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/tutorials/excel-power-automate-returns) and then create a new Word document ([which might not be straightforward](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/details/shared_wordonlinebusiness/word-online-business/)).